# Find the derived set of $S$ where $S=\{m+\frac{1}{n}\mid m,n\in\mathbb N\}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S=\{m+\frac{1}{n}\mid m,n\in\mathbb N\}$. I want to find the derived set (the set of cluster points) of $S$.

I tried this. It seems that the answer is $\mathbb{N}$. So $S\subset[1,\infty)$. Then $$[1,\infty)-\mathbb{N}=(1,2)\cup(2,3)\cup\ldots \cup(k,k+1)\cup \ldots$$ If $x \in (1,2)$ then I was trying to prove that $x$ is not a cluster point of $(1,2)$ and so on. But can't approach to that proof. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Be sure to include the entire mathematical expression between dollar signs.

Comment: What are $m$ and $n$? What do you mean by "derived set"?

Comment: Oh! Sorry i didn't mention this. Here $m$ & $n$ both natural numbers. And derived set= set of all cluster points

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$. Indeed, if $m\in\mathbb{N}$ then $m$ is the limit point of the sequence $(m+1/n)_{n=1}^\infty$ that is a sequence of $S$. Also, $\infty$ is the limit point of the sequence $(m+1)_{m=1}^\infty$, also a sequence of $S$. Now how do we prove that there is nothing else in that set? Obviously, the only possible limit points are positive numbers. Take $x>0$ not an integer and let $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x\in(N,N+1)$. let $m+1/n\in S$. If $m<N$, then $m+1/n\leq N$ hence the distance of all those elements of $S$ from $x$ is at least $h:=x-N>0$. If $m\geq N+1$, then $m+1/n>N+1$, therefore the distance of these elements of $S$ from $x$ is at least $h':=N+1-x>0$. The only elements of $S$ left for us to check are $(N+1/n)_{n=1}^\infty$. But this is a sequence that converges to $N$, hence it cannot have a subsequence converging to $x$. Therefore we have proved that $x$ is not the limit of any sequence formed by elements of $S$, hence not in the cluster set of $S$.

Note: In case you are not interested in sequences converging to infinity but only in sequences converging to *elements of* $\mathbb{R}$, forget about that part.

Comment: I guess OP wants to consider $S$ as a subset of $\mathbb R$. In that case, what is $\infty$?

Comment: @Ennar Okay, maybe there is no space for sequences converging to infinity. Otherwise its the one point compactification of the line. I will add a note, thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Pick $x\in (k,k+1)$. If it were cluster point of $S$, every neighborhood of $x$ would contain a point from $S\setminus\{x\}$. But, $x\in [k+\frac 1{n+1},k+\frac 1n]$ for some natural $n$ and $k+\frac 1{n+1}$, $k+\frac 1n$ are the closest points of $S$ to $x$. Can you find a neighborhood that proves $x$ is not a limit point of $S$?